# Google App Engine providing .well-known Folder

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to provide a `.well-known` folder under my Google App Engine Application I'm using the standard environment and the python27 runtime.
with a `web-app-origin-association.json` file to try the Progressive Web Apps as URL Handlers
origin trial from chrome.

I've added the following code to my app.yaml file under handlers:

```
  # .well-known Ordner
  - url: /.well-known/(.*)
    static_files: well-known/\1
    upload: well-known/.*
```

The folder in my project is named well-known without a dot cause I've read that there are problems when using a folder Name with a dot at the start of the foldername.
But the url `https://example.com/.well-known/web-app-origin-associate.json` isn't available instead it works without the dot:

[image]

What do I have to change in order to make it work under `https://example.com/.well-known/web-app-origin-association.json`?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Flex or Standard environment? Which runtime?

Comment: @FaridShumbar I'm using the standard environment :)

Comment: @FaridShumbar Runtime: python27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way i found out about is to just do it like that:

```
  - url: /\.well-known
    static_dir: .well-known
    secure: always
```

and use the python39 runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the workaround documented at ["Make skip_files rule explicit and tweak to allow .well-known/* to upload"](https://github.com/google/node-sec-roadmap/blob/master/app.yaml#L67):

`^(.*/)?\.(?!well-known(?:/|$)).*$`

You many want to [migrate to Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3) as described in the guide:

> Starting on January 1, 2020, the Python community will no longer
> update, fix bugs, or patch security issues for Python 2.7. We
> recommend that you update apps that are still running in the Python 2
> runtime of the App Engine standard environment to the Python 3 runtime
> as soon as possible.

Comment: @Farid Shumbar it doesn't work I tried multiple things right now i've added this entry to the skip files section:

`- ^(.*/)?\.(?!well-known(?:/|$)).*$`

And my handler entry looks like this:

`  # .well-known Ordner
  - url: /.well-known/(.*\.(json|txt))$
    static_files: well-known/\1
    upload: well-known/.*`